# Flutter - Save token in the response header in sharedpreference

Tags: api, flutter

how to save token passed in response header in sharedpreference.im sharing code below:

```
Future<DriverModel> _handleLogin(Int country_code, Int phone, String password) async {
var jsonData = null;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Map data = {
  'phone': {
    'country_code': country_code,
    'phone': phone,
  },
  'password': password,
};
var body = json.encode(data);
final response = await http.post(
  AuthApi.login,
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  body: body,
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(response.headers.entries);
  
  return DriverModel.fromJson(jsonData);
} else {
  return DriverModel.fromJson(jsonData);
}
```

}

Comment: I think the token shouldn't be saved in shared preference, since it is not secure. Why don't you use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the token, pass the same to the following function.

```
updateToken(String token) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('token', token);
}
```

But as far as I know, credentials such as tokens shouldn't be saved to shared preference, rather you should use [flutter secured storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage).

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

// Create storage
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Unique key for token
final keyToken = 'token';

// Write token value 
await storage.write(key: keyToken , value: tokenValue);

// Read token value 
String value = await storage.read(key: keyToken );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 token_read() async {
 final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 final key = 'token';
 final read_value = prefs.getString(key) ?? 0;
 print('read: $read_value');
return read_value;
  }

token_save(token) async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final key = 'token';
final value = token;
prefs.setString(key, value);
print('saved $value');
}
```

//read the token

```
var readToken = await token_read();
```